# Using jquery-file-upload with rails progress bar not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to allow uploading of videos to s3 through my website. Currently the videos are uploaded properly however the progress bar doesn't work. Is there something that I need to do to get the bar to work? I followed this [guide](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6) and here is my project [repo](https://github.com/TSwimson/videoApp). I have been working on this for many hours and haven't made much progress. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Here are the relevant files [The new video page](https://github.com/TSwimson/videoApp/blob/master/videoApp/app/views/videos/new_new.html.erb), [The controller](https://github.com/TSwimson/videoApp/blob/master/videoApp/app/controllers/videos_controller.rb), and [The model](https://github.com/TSwimson/videoApp/blob/master/videoApp/app/models/video.rb)

Comment: Try this gem: https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails. This should make your life little easy with Jquery File upload. There's a pro railscasts too: http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload.

Comment: Thanks for the tip unfortunately I have already tried to use that gem and I could get it to work. And I would like to watch that cast but can't pay.

Comment: Then you can have a look at the code of that railscasts here: https://github.com/railscasts/381-jquery-file-upload. It uses carrierwave and jqeury file upload, but for uploading images, not videos. I hope you'll be able to at least understand the pattern form code.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not seeing where he used jquery-upload or really any difference between the before and after folders.

Comment: Here's the coffee code: https://github.com/railscasts/381-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/gallery-after/app/assets/javascripts/paintings.js.coffee and here he has included the jqeury file upload: https://github.com/railscasts/381-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/gallery-after/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: Awesome thanks! That will give me something to work with.

Comment: Let SO know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my error was in the styling of my progress bar I was using some bootstrap 2 classes when I meant to use bootstrap 3.